# Finding the m Largest Numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap

This is a problem from the Cormen text, but I'd like to see if there are any other solutions.

Given an array with n distinct numbers, you need to find the m largest ones in the array, and have
them in sorted order. Assume n and m are large, but grow differently. In particular, you need
to consider below the situations where m = t*n, where t is a small number, say 0.1, and then the
possibility m = √n.

The solution given in the book offers 3 options:

1. Sort the array and return the top m-long segment
2. Convert the array to a max-heap and extract the m elements
3. Select the m-th largest number, partition the array about it, and sort the segment of larger entries.

These all make sense, and they all have their pros and cons, but I'm wondering, is there another way to do it? It doesn't have to be better or faster, I'm just curious to see if this is a common problem with more solutions, or if we are limited to those 3 choices.

Comment: Walk through the array `m` times keeping track of your last max to grab the one that is nearest without going over. Price is right style.

Comment: Mb something like this. Have smth like priority queue length `m`, put numbers their in order, so at the begin on queue is the largest number and at the end the smallest one. Then you take next number and if it is  smaller then the smallest one you don't do smth at all oversize you insert it to wright order. It is same as max-heap at point 2. but we have a limited heap(or queue, not sure what will be better)

Comment: @C.B.if `m` too big you have O(n^2), it is faster to sort it with quick sort

Comment: @MikeMinaev Are you calling C.B. an idiot? He knows the method he offered is terrible. The OP said any other method, even if it's slower.

Comment: @ooga nope. But as i think the best algorithm - is the fastest. If i was wrong so - use sleep sort, last m forks, which are still sleeping - your answer

Comment: @MikeMinaev: in the case where `m = sqrt(n)`, this becomes `o(n^1.5)` which is not bad (still not as good as `n*log(n)` though). In the case `m = 0.1 * n`,  it does fall back to `o(n^2)` too, though. In the case where `m` is a constant and does not depend on `n`, @C.B. solution is `o(n)`, so it really depends on how `m` evolve, which is quite the topic of the question.

Comment: Print the numbers out on paper, cut each one out individually and hand one each to a bunch of children, but give bigger numbers to bigger children. Then let then fight it out. I haven't worked out the bugs yet, but it's fun to watch.

Comment: @njzk2 it's no `O(n)` because `O` means the worst case, worst case when `m` is near `n` so.. `O(n^2)`. If you can be sure then values of your array is between `MAX_INT` you can use counting sort, witch is `O(n)` by time

Comment: @MikeMinaev: which is why I specified `In the case where m is a constant and does not depend on n`... The whole exercise is to compare approaches for different behaviors of `m`.

Answer (score 3):

The time complexities of the three approaches you have mentioned are as follows.

1. O(n log n)
2. O(n + m log n)
3. O(n + m log m)

So option (3) is definitely better than the others in terms of asymptotic complexity, since m <= n. When m is small, the difference between (2) and (3) is so small it would have little practical impact.

As for other ways to solve the problem, there are infinitely many ways you could, so the question is somewhat poor in this regard. Another approach I can think of as being practically simple and performant is the following.

1. Extract the first m numbers from your list of n into an array, and sort it.
2. Repeatedly grab the next number from your list and insert it into the correct location in the array, shifting all the lesser numbers over by one and pushing one out.

I would only do this if m was very small though. Option (2) from your original list is also extremely easy to implement if you have a max-heap implementation and will work great.

Comment: not sure how you compute the 3rd complexity? (not sure how we would `Select the m-th largest number` either)

Comment: also, can you define `When m is small`?

Comment: @njzk2 [Median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm, O(n), followed by some O(m log m) sort (such as mergesort) is how I got the complexity for option (3).

Comment: @njzk2 "When m is small" has dubious meaning. It really means "try it and profile it to see if its fast enough for your needs." Or it could mean "when m is some small fixed constant like 10 or 100."

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 radix sort is o(n) for known-sized numbers, but really o(n.log(n)) for any numbers.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: still, for unknown numbers, we cannot really say the radix size is constant. rather, it is in `log(n)`

Answer (score 3):

A different approach.

Take the first m numbers, and turn them into a min heap.  Run through the array, if its value exceeds the min of the top m then you extract the min value and insert the new one.  When you reach the end of the array you can then extract the elements into an array and reverse it.

The worst case performance of this version is `O(n log(m))` placing it between the first and second methods for efficiency.

The average case is more interesting.  On average only `O(m log(n/m))` of the elements are going to pass the first comparison test, each time incurring `O(log(m))` work so you get `O(n + m log(n/m) log(m))` work, which puts it between the second and third methods.  **But** if `n` is many orders of magnitude greater than `m` then the `O(n)` piece dominates, and the `O(n)` median select in the third approach has worse constants than the one comparison per element in this approach, so in this case this is actually the fastest!

Comment: If you insert the values extracted from the min heap into the result array from last index to first, you don't even need to reverse it.